# Изменить значение параметра используя функцию

Tags: c

У меня есть в функции main уже определенный парметр со значением 3.И я хочу создать функцию, которая возьмет мой парметр и например прибавит к нему 2.И потом вернет этот параметр с уже новым значением.Я пытался использовать static, но что то не получается.И при использовании printf выведется уже новое значение.Заранее благодарю.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int p){
  p=p+2;
  return p;
} 

int main(void)
{
  static int i = 3;
  f(i);
  
  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i = f(i);` ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто присвойте переменной результат функции:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int p){
  p=p+2;
  return p;
} 

int main(void)
{
  int i = 3;
  i = f(i);
  
  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Либо, ели не хотите так, воспользуйтесь указателями:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *p){
  *p = *p+2;
} 

int main(void)
{
  int i = 3;
  f(&i);
  
  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант не работает почему-то, но зато второй помог)Спасибо, @rusgeli)

Comment: @Steve, не заметил, что у вас функция типа `void`, который ничего не должен возвращать. У вас там должен был быть `int` вместо `void`, если вы собирались возвращать интовое значение из нее. Поправил ответ.